# Can't execute AWS Lambda function built with Micronaut and Graal: Error decoding JSON stream

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, micronaut, graalvm

I built a native java AWS Lambda function using Graal and Micronaut as explained [here](https://guides.micronaut.io/micronaut-function-aws-lambda/guide/index.html)

After deploying it to AWS Lambda (custom runtime), I can't successfully execute it.

The error that AWS shows is:

```
{
  "errorType": "Runtime.ExitError",
  "errorMessage": "RequestId: 9a231ad9-becc-49f7-832a-f9088f821fb2 Error: Runtime exited with error: exit status 1"
}
```

The AWS log output is:

```
START RequestId: 9a231ad9-becc-49f7-832a-f9088f821fb2 Version: $LATEST
01:13:08.015 [main] INFO  i.m.context.env.DefaultEnvironment - Established active environments: [ec2, cloud, function]
Error executing function (Use -x for more information): Error decoding JSON stream for type [request]: No content to map due to end-of-input
 at [Source: (BufferedInputStream); line: 1, column: 0]
END RequestId: 9a231ad9-becc-49f7-832a-f9088f821fb2
REPORT RequestId: 9a231ad9-becc-49f7-832a-f9088f821fb2  Duration: 698.31 ms Billed Duration: 700 ms     Memory Size: 512 MB Max Memory Used: 54 MB  
RequestId: 9a231ad9-becc-49f7-832a-f9088f821fb2 Error: Runtime exited with error: exit status 1
Runtime.ExitError
```

But when I test it locally using

```
echo '{"value":"testing"}' | ./server
```

I got

```
01:35:56.675 [main] INFO  i.m.context.env.DefaultEnvironment - Established active environments: [function]
{"value":"New value: testing"}
```

The function code is:

```
@FunctionBean("user-data-function")
public class UserDataFunction implements Function<UserDataRequest, UserData> {

    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(UserDataFunction.class);

    private final UserDataService userDataService;

    public UserDataFunction(UserDataService userDataService) {
        this.userDataService = userDataService;
    }

    @Override
    public UserData apply(UserDataRequest request) {
        if (LOG.isDebugEnabled()) {
            LOG.debug("Request: {}", request.getValue());
        }

        return userDataService.get(request.getValue());
    }
}
```

And the UserDataService is:

```
@Singleton
public class UserDataService {

    public UserData get(String value) {
        UserData userData = new UserData();
        userData.setValue("New value: " + value);

        return userData;
    }
}
```

To test it on AWS console, I configured the following test event:

```
{ "value": "aws lambda test" }
```

PS.: I uploaded to AWS Lambda a zip file that contains the "server" and the "bootstrap" file to allow the "custom runtime" as explained before.

What I'm doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Tiago Peixoto.

EDIT: added the lambda test event used on AWS console.

Answer (score 3):

Ok, I figured it out. I just changed the bootstrap file from this

```
#!/bin/sh
set -euo pipefail
./server
```

to this

```
#!/bin/sh
set -euo pipefail

# Processing
while true
do
  HEADERS="$(mktemp)"
  # Get an event
  EVENT_DATA=$(curl -sS -LD "$HEADERS" -X GET "http://${AWS_LAMBDA_RUNTIME_API}/2018-06-01/runtime/invocation/next")
  REQUEST_ID=$(grep -Fi Lambda-Runtime-Aws-Request-Id "$HEADERS" | tr -d '[:space:]' | cut -d: -f2)

  # Execute the handler function from the script
  RESPONSE=$(echo "$EVENT_DATA" | ./server)

  # Send the response
  curl -X POST "http://${AWS_LAMBDA_RUNTIME_API}/2018-06-01/runtime/invocation/$REQUEST_ID/response"  -d "$RESPONSE"
done
```

as explained [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/runtimes-walkthrough.html)

Comment: Can you explain what the difference is?

Comment: Inside the second version of the shell script there is a loop that reads the lambda runtime api: "http://${AWS_LAMBDA_RUNTIME_API}/2018-06-01/runtime/invocation/next", so it´s possible to get the event data from there.